# EF CodeFirst Seed method do not make any changes in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, seeding

I'm trying to insert some default values in database via method Seed. All code look completely correct as far as I can see. But after running `update-database` command there is no new records as expected. Probably I'm missing some details. Could you please advise how can I fix this?

```
public class JwtContext : DbContext
    {

        public JwtContext() : base("name=Jwt")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new JwtDbInitializer<JwtContext>());
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Audience> Audience { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Roles> Roles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Roles>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Users)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Roles)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.RoleId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Audience>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Users)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Audiences)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.AudienceId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        }
        private class JwtDbInitializer<T> : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<JwtContext>
        {
            protected override void Seed(JwtContext context)
            {
                base.Seed(context);
                var audience = new Audience
                {
                    ClientId = "some_client_id",
                    Base64Secret = "some_secret",
                    Name = "Agromash.Api"
                };
                context.Audience.Add(audience);
                context.SaveChanges();
                IList<Roles> defaultRole = new List<Roles>();
                defaultRole.Add(new Roles { Name = "Admin" });
                defaultRole.Add(new Roles { Name = "Moder" });
                defaultRole.Add(new Roles { Name = "User" });
                foreach (var role in defaultRole)
                {
                    context.Roles.Add(role);
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
                var user = new Users { Email = "email", IsActive = true, Password = "password", RoleId = 1, AudienceId = 1 };
                //SiteGlobal.Email, Password = SiteGlobal.Password
                context.Users.Add(user);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: update-database command => are you using ef code first migration?

Comment: @DanNguyen, yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to this article http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1689, it's not possible to use migration AND "DropCreateDatabaseAlways" as the initializer at the same time.

> Closed Sep 28, 2013 at 4:56 AM by RoMiller
>   EF Team Triage: This is 'By Design' and was an intentional change we took in EF6. If this initializer is used to create the database then a single entry is added to the __MigrationsHistory table which then renders the database un-usable with migrations (since these initializers don't use your migrations to create the database). This has confused a large number of people in previous releases, so we opted to not automatically create database/schema when migrations is enabled.
>
> You can use the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer if you just
>   want your migrations to be applied. If you want to drop the database
>   then you could easily wrap this in a custom initializer that includes
>   a call to context.Database.Delete().

```
public JwtContext() : base("name=Jwt")
    {
        // to alter the database.This tell the database to close all connection and if a transaction is open to rollback this one.
         Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction
            , string.Format("ALTER DATABASE {0} SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE", Database.Connection.Database));

        Database.Delete();
        Database.SetInitializer(new JwtDbInitializer<JwtContext>());
    }
```

Comment: Such using of context will make recursive call.

Comment: Nope, it's not working as well, there is problem regarding default user permissions. But even if to solve these problems I suppose this would not work.

Comment: Finally, I solved this problem another way, but your post gave me idea.